# Permalink shows garbage character

Tags: permalinks

[image]

Prmalink is visible like this, any solution https://www.crackpcs.com/%e0%a4%ae%e0%a4%…%a5%87-%e0%a4%a4/

Answer (score 0):

As the post title is in Hindi, the permalink generator tried to translate it into English. Failing to do so, it has converted it to symbols. If you translate each post tile into Hindi manually, and then type that into the permalink field, all lower-case with dashes in-between, it should work. Sorry if that's a problem.

Reason for this is that all URLs can only be in English. Find more about it [here.](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/why-are-web-addresses-in-english.htm)